# How would I delete Products that has value over a specific amount in magento?

Tags: magento-1.8

I am looking for sql code that will allow me to delete products from my magento database that is over a certain price. Can some help me with this code please.

Comment: Why do you need the SQL code instead of php code to delete products?

Answer (score 0):

To start, do this:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
echo $collection->getSelect()->__toString();
```

and once you have the query to load all the products you will be able to modify it according to your needs.